# Boston DJs Brian and Ivan of Shizm contact info

Tags: house, dj, where-are-they-now

20 years ago there were very good house DJs named Brian and Ivan of Shizm. They released excellent mixes on a website which is no longer active. Ten years later, I dug deep and could find that Ivan had a forum on Yahoo: I wrote him an email and he answered openly and friendly. After some time, I deleted all my emails and now I want to follow-up and know more about what happened. Is there any info about these DJs? How I can write a letter to Ivan or Brian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ivan is very friendly indeed, here's his SC account you can message him
https://soundcloud.com/movement-wkkl

Ps: do you own shizm mixes yourself?

Comment: I downloaded the mp3 files when they were at shizm.com but in 2001 the site was shut down

Comment: @NiklasR. I have around 90 shizm mixes myself, do you mind trading? I'm willing to give you all of mine, if you give me yours, I'm trying to get them all.        
soundcloud.com/jc012  <<<< Message me here if you're interested.

Comment: I'll write you there then. I still have the mp3 files